# Симметричная ли матрица?

Tags: python, python-3.x, инспекция-кода, матрицы

Подскажите что не правильно. Работает не при всех входных данных

```
n = int(input())
a = []
for i in range(n):
    a.append(list(map(int, input().split())))

for i in range (len(a)):
    for j in range (len(a[i])):
        if a[i][j]!=a[j][i]:
            break
            print("no")

print("yes")
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: Вам подходит моё решение? Если да, то отметьте его как верное.

Answer (score 2):

Давайте разбираться постепенно.

## Шаг 1

Вы не выводите "no":

```
n = int(input())
a = []
for i in range(n):
    a.append(list(map(int, input().split())))

for i in range (len(a)):
    for j in range (len(a[i])):
        if a[i][j]!=a[j][i]:
            print("no")  #  break
            break  #  print("no")

print("yes")
```

## Шаг 2

В ряде случаев, Вы будете дважды выводить "no". Поэтому следует использовать дополнительный флаг:

```
n = int(input())
a = []
for i in range(n):
    a.append(list(map(int, input().split()))) 

stop = False
for i in range (len(a)):
    for j in range (len(a[i])):
        if a[i][j]!=a[j][i]:
            print("no")
            stop = True
            break
    if stop:
        break

print("yes")
```

## Шаг 3

В заключение, не следует выводить после "no", "yes":

```
n = int(input())
a = []
for i in range(n):
    a.append(list(map(int, input().split()))) 

stop = False
for i in range (len(a)):
    for j in range (len(a[i])):
        if a[i][j]!=a[j][i]:
            print("no")
            stop = True
            break
    if stop:
        break

if not stop:
    print("yes")
```

## Замечания по коду

Используйте одну переменную в коде для обозначения размерности. Так улучшается читаемость:

```
n = int(input())
a = []
for i in range(n):
    a.append(list(map(int, input().split()))) 

stop = False
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if a[i][j] != a[j][i]:
            print("no")
            stop = True
            break
    if stop:
        break

if not stop:
    print("yes")
```

Пользуйтесь функциями. Тогда отпадёт надобность в сложных конструкциях с флагами:

```
def read_matrix():
    n = int(input())
    a = []
    for i in range(n):
        a.append(list(map(int, input().split()))) 
    return a

def is_symmetry(a):
    n = len(a)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if a[i][j] != a[j][i]:
                return False
    return True

a = read_matrix()
s = is_symmetry()
if s:
   print("yes")
else:
   print("no")
```

Ещё раз пользуйтесь функциями:

```
def read_matrix():
    n = int(input())
    a = []
    for i in range(n):
        a.append(list(map(int, input().split()))) 
    return a   

def is_row_correct(a, i, j):
    n = len(a)
    for j in range(n):
        if a[i][j] == a[j][i]:
            continue
        return False
    return True
         
def is_symmetry(a):
    n = len(a)
    for i in range(n):
        correct = is_row_correct(a, i, j)
        if not correct:
           return False
    return True

a = read_matrix()
s = is_symmetry()
if s:
   print("yes")
else:
   print("no")
```

Чего добились? Можем делать библиотеку. Например:

```
import core


a = core.read_matrix()
s = core.is_symmetry()
if s:
   print("yes")
else:
   print("no")
```

В библиотеке код написан практически словами естественного языка. Возможно, имеет смысл чутка над названиями подумать:

```
def read_matrix():
    n = int(input())
    a = []
    for i in range(n):
        a.append(list(map(int, input().split()))) 
    return a   

def is_row_correct(a, i, j):
    n = len(a)
    for j in range(n):
        if a[i][j] == a[j][i]:
            continue
        return False
    return True
         
def is_symmetry(a):
    n = len(a)
    for i in range(n):
        correct = is_row_correct(a, i, j)
        if not correct:
           return False
    return True
```

Comment: вот только вы в итоге оставили флаг ```stop``` в коде, но при этом он не используется. )

Comment: @n1tr0xs готово

Answer (score 0):

1. `print("yes")` будет выводиться всегда, не зависимо от того когда цикл закончится.
2. break стоит перед `print("no")`, значит цикл завершится, а вывода "no" не произойдет.

Чтобы программа заработала в таком виде, я бы добавил `exit()`, вместо break тогда, в случае если матрица не симметричная, программа выведет "no" и завершится, не дойдя до `print("yes")`

```
n = int(input())
a = []
for i in range(n):
    a.append(list(map(int, input().split())))

for i in range (len(a)):
    for j in range (len(a[i])):
        if a[i][j]!=a[j][i]:
            print("no")
            exit()

print("yes")
```